# Можно ли сказать "Канун приближается"?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Например, "Приближается канун Рождества" или "Приближается канун Дня всех святых". Есть мнения, что это или плеоназм, или тавтология, или даже оксюморон.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

КАНУН,  чего. ДЕНЬ, предшествующий празднику. К. Нового года. К. Рождества. В к. праздника. День или период времени, предшествующий какому-л. событию.

Выражение "приближается канун" используется не часто, в Нацкорпусе примеров нет. Собственно говоря, не так много поводов для применения  этого сочетания.

Хэллоуин - это канун Дня всех святых. Рождественский сочельник - это канун Рождества. Таким образом, канун этих праздников также является особенным днем, носящим собственное имя. В этих случаях использование выражения "приближается канун"  не вызывает вопросов.

Приближается канун Дня всех святых, то есть Хэллоуин. Приближается канун рождества, то есть Рождественский сочельник.

Приближается канун Нового года - это звучит странно. Здесь канун мыслится как период времени, но он весьма неопределенный.

Comment: На самом деле выражение "Канун нового года" вполне оправдано. 

Кану́н Но́вого го́да (англ. New Year's Eve) — последний день года по григорианскому календарю, предшествующий Новому году. В современной традиции является отдельным от Нового года праздником, во время которого начинаются торжества по встрече следующего года. Во многих культурах в праздновании используются фейерверки и прочая пиротехника. В России канун Нового года считается рабочим днём, однако, фактически семейные застолья и празднования начинаются вечером, до наступления самого Нового года.( По Википедии)

Answer (score 4):

Канун - это день перед праздником или каким-то событием. Этот день тоже может быть важен, ожидаем, он может быть организован как-то по-особенному. Поэтому и канун можно ждать, а значит и канун может приближаться.

Однако если говорящий имеет в виду сам день праздника, то тогда это, конечно, речевая ошибка.

Comment: Да, Екатерина, вы правы: если имеется сам праздник, тогда, безусловно,  речевая ошибка.

Comment: Имеется ввиду именно канун праздника, а не сам праздник, потому и возник спор. То есть праздник может приближаться, а канун нет, так как это и есть предшествующее (или приближающееся)  время празднику, как-то так.

Comment: Вы не поняли, Аннет. Если под кануном понимать праздник, тогда речевая ошибка. А если имеется в виду канун как день перед каким-то праздником или событием, как, например, в вашем случае, тогда никакой ошибки нет.

Comment: "Если под кануном понимать праздник, тогда речевая ошибка".

То есть, если я жду канун (в нашем случае ночь Хэллоуина), то всё ок. Если жду самого Дня всех святых и говорю, что приближается его канун - то это ошибка.

Так?

Comment: Да, вы правы.

Answer (score 3):

***Тавтология*** - это повторение однокоренных слов, а ***плеоназм*** -  средство лексической выразительности, основанное на использовании в предложении или тексте близких по значению слов, создающих смысловую избыточность. 
Оксюморон - это фигура речи , основанная на сочетании несочетаемого. Напр.: Живой труп, Мертвые души.
А теперь выясним значение слова " канун".

КАНУН, -а; м. [от греч. kanōn - правило, норма]
чего.
***День, предшествующий празднику.*** К. Нового года. К. Рождества. В к. праздника. //
***День или период времени, предшествующий какому-л. событию***. Дебаты в к. выборов. К. встречи.

Следовательно, приближаться может не только сам праздник, но и канун - день предшествующий празднику.  Никакой тавтологии, ни плеоназма здесь нет. Праздник и канун - это два разных понятия.